# "Array& params": How to understand "&" after "Array" - type modifer?

Tags: blockchain, c++

I'm trying to understand how "invalidateblock"-function works, literally line by line.

Since I'm at basic level in C++, I couldn't explain to myself what's the "&" after "Array" there to achieve though I know of references and pointers and though I've found out that it's a so called "type modifier". Still I'm wondering "Array" is a type just like "int", "char" etc.

Where can I find more information on where Array is defined/explained?What are member functions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not related to Bitcoin specifically and would be better suited for http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Ok, but I asked it here in order to hear developer's answers or comments who have written the code and are represented in Bitcoi.SE.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the particular software your question is about?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I've been looking at `rpcblockchain.cpp` of bitcoin-0.10.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of the JSON code. An [Array](https://www.json.com/json-array) is a JSON entity that contains an ordered list of zero or more JSON entities. As its name, "params", suggests, this one contains the parameters to the command. So when you see:

```
std::string strHash = params[0].get_str();
```

That gets the first parameter into a `string` called `strHash`. This makes sense since the first (and only) parameter to invalidateblock is a hash, as this help text indicates:

```
        "invalidateblock \"hash\"\n"
        "\nPermanently marks a block as invalid, as if it violated a consensus rule.\n"
        "\nArguments:\n"
        "1. hash   (string, required) the hash of the block to mark as invalid\n"
        "\nResult:\n"
        "\nExamples:\n"
```

Comment: Thanks! But what's the purpose of "&" after "Array"? I think type modifiers, such as "&", are used in programming to convert a data type into another and obviously Array is being converted into a reference type while it's defined in the "invalidateblock"-function so can I assume that this conversion makes references out of Array's params? And if yes, *what variables* are they references to? What do they have to do with `get_str()`?

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi It sounds like you need to learn C++ and then come back and look at this code.

Comment: I know I'm not using the best technical terms but would you give me a hint to understand: why I need to put a "&" after "Array" though - to my limited knowledge - you could leave it away and simply write ‍‍‍`Value invalidateblock(const Array params, bool fHelp)
{...‎‎‏}`? - I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20027/JSON-Spirit-A-C-JSON-Parser-Generator-Implemented) but it's not really helping to understand this problem. But I think get_str() is just putting the hash value as a string to params[0]!?

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi Why do you think you *need* to do that? In this case, the parameter could be passed by value or by reference, but passing by reference is cheaper. Competent C++ coders reflexively pass "complex" classes by reference when that is possible because it avoids copying the value.

Comment: David Schwartz, thanks! Finally you gave the answer and I can sleep well :D +1